# Who to access field of nested relationship in soql where first relation is simple and next is polymorphic

Tags: salesforce, soql

I want to access custom field of Owner (User) fields where Owner is polymorphic relation it can be either User or Group.
I tried following query:

```
SELECT Id, Email, Name, Lead.TYPEOF Owner WHEN User THEN custom__c FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId='xxxxxx'
```

Relationship stack is:
**Lead > Owner (User,Group) > custom__c**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT      field1__c, 
            field2__c 
FROM        Lead 
WHERE       Owner.type = 'User' 
  AND       CampaignID = 'xxxxxx'
```

EDIT:

Leaving my original answer in case it helps someone else.

I believe what you are looking for is this:

```
SELECT Id, Email, Name,
    TYPEOF Lead.Owner
        WHEN User THEN custom__c
    END
FROM CampaignMember
WHERE Field != 'value'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my target object is CampaignMember and I also want to select some fields of CampaignMember object.

Comment: Ok. Maybe spell out in pseudo code what you are trying to do. Does `WHERE  Lead.Owner.type = 'User'` work for your use case?

Comment: I want to get all CampaignMember with additional information about if member is lead, owner is user otherwise it will give null. I appreciate you gave time to my query. Thanks

Comment: I know, I can get some basic information from polymorphic object "Name" but it won't be work for custom fields.

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know if I got your question right this time!